# Project Euler 138 - C code not storing numbers correctly

Tags: c

I am a beginner in the language C and am aiming to answer problem 138 on Project Euler. For your benefit here is the link: https://projecteuler.net/problem=138

So shown below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long L(unsigned long long b);

int main() {

    unsigned long long sigma = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int b = 16;
    while (n < 12) {

        unsigned long long l = L(b);
        if (l != 0) {
            n++;
            sigma += l;
        }
        b++;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", sigma);
}

unsigned long long L(unsigned long long b) {

    unsigned long long L = 0;
    unsigned long long X1 = 5 * (b * b) + (8 * b) + 4;
    unsigned long long x1 = sqrt(X1);
    unsigned long long X2 = 5 * (b * b) - (8 * b) + 4;
    unsigned long long x2 = sqrt(X2);

    if (X1 == x1 * x1 && x1 % 2 == 0) {
        L += x1 / 2;
    }
    if (X2 == x2 * x2 && x2 % 2 == 0) {
        L += x2 / 2;
    }
    return L;
}
```

As the question asks for the first twelve I have set the loop to terminate when n = 12, however this code does not give the correct answer. I initially though there was a logic error but when I set the loop to terminate one n = 2, the program gave the correct answer. I suspect that it has something to do with the numbers being stored in the variable but of course I could be wrong.

Could anyone shed some light on this as I'm pretty sure the logic is correct?

Comment: One possible problem is that [`sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) is a floating-point function, so the result might be truncated. And please try to avoid variables so closely named as `X1` and `x1`, they are hard to distinguish. Same with the function `L` and the local variable `L` *inside* the `L` function.

Comment: So is there any work around to this?

Comment: @JohnDoe Change all your integer types to floating-point types.

Comment: The reason I am using integers types is to check whether a given integer is a perfect square. If I were to use floating point types, wouldn't the line 'if X1 == x1*x1' always evaluate as true, even for integers such as 2?

Comment: For example, C evaluates sqrt(2) as 1 and so 1*1 == 2 evaluates as false. This line determines that 2 is not a perfect square.

Comment: Many Project Euler questions are designed to exceed the bounds and precisions of normal integer and floating-point types, so they require special techniques to compute

Comment: I have checked the answer to the problem and the integer in question is well within the bounds of the unsigned long long type.

Comment: The answer may be in bounds, but are all of the intermediate calculations?

Comment: @JohnDoe: The answer may be within bounds, and even the intermediate values may be within bounds of the integer types you use, but, by calling `sqrt`, you are using a `double` type with only 53 bits of precision.

Comment: Using the Pythagorean Theorem on the right triangle with sides "L", "h" and "b/2", and then substituting h = b+1 or b-1, I came to the following equation 5*(b^2) + 8*b + 4 = 4L^2  and  5*(b^2) - 8*b + 4  = 4L^2. Therefore there the expression on the LHS must be a perfect square and the square root of the expression must be divisible by 2. As I mentioned in my OP, the logic hold for finding the first 2 triangles but breaks down for the first 12. So I'm pretty sure its a data type problem

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is there any way I can get better precision?

Answer (score 0):

1. The largest value of `b` passed to `L` would be at least 2,168,393,136. However, if an `int` is 32 bits, this overflows the maximum value of an `int`, 2,147,483,647. `b` should be made an `unsigned int` (or any wider integer type).
2. The function `L` computes `5*b*b + 8*b + 4`. Since the largest `b` is slightly over 2<sup>31</sup>, the mathematical value of this expression is somewhat over 2<sup>64</sup>. Unless `unsigned long long` is wider than 64 bits, this exceeds the maximum value of `unsigned long long`, with the result that an undesired value is computed.
3. `L` applies `sqrt` to `X1` (and `X2`). This converts the value to `double`, which commonly has 53 bits of precision. Since the value has 65 bits, 12 bits are lost. Fortunately, the derivative of square root is very small at this magnitude, so large changes in the input produce small changes in the output. So the result of `sqrt` should be near the exact mathematical result, and it should be feasible to adjust the result to find the integer nearest the exact mathematical square root, and then that can be used to test whether `X1` is an exact square. Alternatively, an integer square root routine could be written.
4. Once the above problems are fixed, the program may continue further than before, which will result in larger values of `b` being used. Continuing evaluation may be necessary to ensure the types are wide and precise enough for the work. (I tried a kludge to extend the domain the code can support. It is currently running with b exceeding 16 billion. I could have a bug, but I think you should be prepared for considerably larger numbers.)

In summary, the native types of C and common implementations do not support doing this arithmetic directly. It is necessary to write special code to handle the large numbers or to work around them.

As the point of Euler Project problems like this is to push the boundaries of built-in arithmetic, that is where the answer should stop—the student should continue thinking from there.